# Sending another postMessage in worker.addEventListener

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Main question: is calling `worker.postMessage` from the `worker.addEventListener` bad? Example below, I tried to keep it as short as possible.

I have a GWT native function with a worker (worker is initialized before so I can reuse it. Also, the braces should be `/*-{` and `}-*/` but for the sake for syntax highlighting I just go with `{}`).

```
private native void nativeWorkerCalls(JavaScriptObject worker, int cwidth, int cheight) {
    console.log('Main: Pre draw');
    worker.postMessage({'cmd' : 'draw', 'args' : [cwidth*cheight] });
    
    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        switch (e.data.cmd) {
            case 'draw':
                /* do some stuff */
                console.log('Main: Pre clear');
                worker.postMessage({'cmd' : 'clearBuffer', 'args' : [e.data.offset]}); // I call the worker again!
                break;
            case 'clearBuffer':
                console.log("%c Main: Post clear", 'background: #222; color: #00ffae');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        };
        console.log("Main: ### Finished listener ###");
    }, false);
};
```

and following `worker.js` script which should execute different switch cases depending on the 'cmd' passed.

```
importScripts("emscripten.js");

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;
    switch (data.cmd) {
        case 'draw':
            /* assign some buffer, draw into it */
            self.postMessage({ 'cmd' : 'draw', buffer : mb, offset : buffer});
            break;
        case 'clearBuffer':
            /* clear buffer */
            console.log('Main: Pre clear');
            self.postMessage({'cmd' : 'clearBuffer'});
            break;
        default:
            self.postMessage(null);
        };
}, false);
```

Problem: The first time I run the native function it's all fine. But every following call has the side effect that the eventlistener in worker.js gets called repeatedly.

One run should make following calls:

> Main: Pre draw
>
> Worker: Draw
>
> Main: Post draw
>
> Main: Pre clear
>
> Main: ### Finished listener ###
>
> Worker: Free buffer
>
> Main: Post clear
>
> Main: ### Finished listener ###

Pressing the button a second time gives me too many calls - it adds another draw (which doesn't seem to do anything) and also adds another clear (which runs into an error because the worker will then try to free a buffer that has already been freed):

> Main: Pre draw
>
> Worker: Draw
>
> Main: Post draw
>
> Main: Pre clear
>
> Main: ### Finished listener ###
>
> Main: Post draw
>
> Main: Pre clear
>
> Main: ### Finished listener ###
>
> Worker: Free buffer
>
> Main: Post clear
>
> Main: ### Finished listener ###
>
> Main: Post clear
>
> Main: ### Finished listener ###
>
> Worker: Free buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake on my behalf. The reason why I had these extra calls was because I kept adding event listeners to the worker. Obviously I need to add the event listener where I instantiate the worker and then I can pass the worker around.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is bad, a 3 way round trip in any messaging system is an anti pattern, except for things like protocol discovery.

To avoid this centralize your state in the main thread and send all data including derived data at once.

Comment: I will avoid to have this 3 way trip. But the reason why I had this extra calls was something else :)